# What is the order of precedence for boolean operators in JS?

Tags: javascript, boolean

```
 e.pageX = e.clientX + (html && html.scrollLeft || body && body.scrollLeft || 0) - (html.clientLeft || 0)
```

how would this expression evaluate?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can find a precedence table for Javascript operators on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence. It is a great source for Javascript documentation in general.

Anyway, `&&` has higher precedence than `||` so `a && b || c || d` is equivalent to `(((a && b) || c) || d)`. This is similar to many other language with a C-inspired syntax.